# Retrieve elements through using variable IDs

Tags: android

I have number of check-boxes with their ids as per a pattern sequence.
Like checkboxes1, checkboxes2, checkboxes3 etc..

I want to run a loop keeping each box, retrieve value, perform some function and move on.

Something like:

```
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        String elementId="checkboxes"+Integer.toString(i);
        CheckBox elementcb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.elementId);
    }
```

But of course the above thing won’t work as I can’t just simple append a variable in front of  `R.id.`. So how can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{

    String elementId="checkboxes"+Integer.toString(i);

    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(elementId,"id", getPackageName());

    CheckBox elementcb = (CheckBox) findViewById(resID);
}
```

hope this help :)

Comment: A little explanation why this solves the issue would be nice.

Comment: Well get identifier() return a resource identifier for the given resource name in R . if you open R.java you will see all the defined ids in the inner class called id (ids values are int). findViewByID() takes the int value of id R.id.checkboxes1 .